# Pandas multiple conditions within a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the below df, I need to replace the `COST A` & `COST B` for `E` to `0` and replace Comment as `Un reported cost`, when below conditions are met -

1. E and F have the same cost for 'COST A'
2. E and F have the same cost for 'COST B'

as you can see 20 and 0.5 for E is replace with 0, as E and F have the same cost

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2021','SKU_1','A','0','0','Un reported cost'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','B','0','0','Un reported cost'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','C','0','0','Un reported cost'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','D','0','0','Un reported cost'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','E','0.05','20','Calculated'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','F','0.05','20','Actual']],
                   columns = ['MTH-YR','SKU','TYPE','COST A','COST B','COMMENT'])
```

Expected result,

```
     MTH-YR     SKU   TYPE COST A  COST B  COMMENT
0   1/1/2021    SKU_1   A   0   0   Un reported cost
1   1/1/2021    SKU_1   B   0   0   Un reported cost
2   1/1/2021    SKU_1   C   0   0   Un reported cost
3   1/1/2021    SKU_1   D   0   0   Un reported cost
4   1/1/2021    SKU_1   E   0   0   Un reported cost
5   1/1/2021    SKU_1   F   0.5 20  Actual
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be columns E and F?

Comment: @Acccumulation E and F are in the TYPE column :)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `E==F`? I mean which columns need to be same for you to consider `E==F`?

Comment: @ShaunakSen: 
If cost A for E and F are same (here, 0.5 is same) then, replace with 0 for E cost A).
If cost B for E and F are same (here, 20 is same) then, replace with 0 for E cost B).
then, chnage comment for E to 'Un reported Cost'

Comment: @ShaunakSen updated my question. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range (len(df["COST A"])):
    # First check for the index of E:
    if df["TYPE"][i] == "E":
        # Then we have two conditions that will be true if E == F
        if df["COST A"][i] == df["COST A"][i+1] and df["COST B"][i] == df["COST B"][i+1]:
            # Now we replace the old values           
            df["COST A"][i] = 0
            df["COST B"][i] = 0
            df["COMMENT"][i] = "Un reported cost"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for this small dataset, use `.iloc` method.

```
## Change COST B for E to 0
df.iloc[4,4] = 0

## Change COMMENT for E to 'Un reported cost'
df.iloc[4,5] = 'Un reported cost'
```

**UPDATE:**
I was playing around with this before going to sleep, and came across this solution on a larger data.

Let's define your data. I have added duplicate E's here.

```
## Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2021','SKU_1','A','0','0','Un reported cost'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','B','0','0','Un reported cost'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','C','0','0','Un reported cost'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','D','0','0','Un reported cost'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','E','0.05','20','Calculated'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','E','0.05','20','Calculated'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','E','0.05','20','Calculated'],
                   ['1/1/2021','SKU_1','F','0.05','20','Actual']],
                   columns = ['MTH-YR','SKU','TYPE','COST A','COST B','COMMENT'])
```

Using list comprehension, we can assign values to `COST B` based on the conditions that you need.

```
df['COST B'] = ['0' if df['TYPE'][x] == 'E' else df['COST B'][x] for x in range(len(df['TYPE']))]
```

In essence, we're just looping through the values in `TYPE` to see which ones are type 'E'. When found, we're changing that value to 0. Otherwise, we're keeping the value stored in `COST B`. Same logic is applied for `COMMENT`.

```
df['COMMENT'] = ['Un reported cost' if df['TYPE'][x] == 'E' else df['COMMENT'][x] for x in range(len(df['TYPE']))]
```

Comment: updated my question. Sorry for confusion.